# Am I losing space on C: to IIS 'sites', and what can i do about it?

Tags: windows, iis, diskspace

**Factoid One:**
I have been happily creating "sites" using IIS.  If I want to try something out, I just start IIS Manager, right-click 'sites', click Add Site, put a folder name in the 'Physical Path' box and add an unused Port number.  There are now 30 entries in the "Sites" list.

In every case, the "Physical Path" is an F: folder, and nothing in any of those folders directly references another drive.

**Factoid Two:**
For months, i've been getting warnings about shrinking C: space.  I go to Settings/System/Storage, and clean up what I can.  I set up a couple of Simlinks to move folders to the much larger F drive.  I get some space back, and pretty soon the messages begin reappearing.

**Factoid Three:**
After the latest warning about space on C:, I began looking around the C: drive (again).  Now I discover C:/Users (how did I miss this before?) has folders whose names correspond with IIS Site Names.  Inside some, and probably all, are folders named AppData, Application Data, Cookies..., a large subset of the folders found in any Users/username folder.

**Finally the question:**
Until I saw (3), I did not suspect a relationship between my naive use of IIS, and disappearing space on C:.  Now I see a relationship, but I don't understand it.  What is it, and how can I create "sites" w/o clobbering my C: drive?  (And why does IIS need to reproduce a user folder, if that's what's happening?)

Comment: In general, C drive is the system disk on a computer. When the Windows operating system runs, it will generate a lot of junk files. No matter you use it or not, the C drive space will become smaller to a certain extent.The memory occupied by the folders in the C:/Users whose names correspond with IIS Site Names is only a small part.You should check those big files and then use scripts to clean it regularly.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that IIS is using much space for those accounts. They are only created/used by IIS so **you** can manage (limit/grant) permissions (file access, db access, nw access, etc) for anonymous visitors to IIS (if your web apps need to do that kind of stuff).

You can check the actual usage (space) for those accounts: right-click and choose Properties for folders within those `c:\users` folders.  Chances-are they will only be around 85 MB.  IIS does keep logs. Those files will grow. They are in your `c:\inetpub\logs\` folder and adjacent folders. Those won't be very big unless you generate **a lot** of traffic to your IIS server.

More likely, your space is being consumed by windows updates.  My pc seems to accumulate 100mb periodically from win updates (I just checked mine: 8.9gb).  Check your `c:\windows\installer` and `c:\windows\temp` folders. Those can be compressed, or if you need the space, you could purge old installer & temp (files older than 2 years).  Just be careful/cautious/gentle with deleting stuff. Don't just take the opinion of one guy on stackoverflow please.

There are other good utilities you could use to find out what is using so much space.

Bottom line: it is very unlikely to be IIS or logs, or utility accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, esp the comment "Don't just take the opinion of one guy... :-).  Another clue, or just annoying factoid, is the rapidity with which space disappears.  I moved a VS folder to another drive, getting about 1.6GB.  I was about to Restart (to complete "Updates"), when my SO wanted to do 'one simple thing'.  She opened mail, copied text from an attached Word document, pasted it into a website's maintenance tool, and done.  Result: back down to 300MB space available.  I move another large folder to F & rebooted, completing "updates".  

But why did 1.2GB disappear so easily?